# navigation after AsyncStorage.setItem: _this3.navigateTo is not a function

Tags: firebase, react-native, native-base

Currently, I am implementing a chat. After user pressed a chat button, the app will navigate the user to the Chat component. The chat content will simply store in firebase and chatId is needed to identify which chat belongs to the user.

Since I don't know how to pass `props` during navigation, I decided to save the CurrentChatId in AsyncStorage. After navigated to the Chat component, it will get the CurrentChatId from AsyncStorage so that I can map the chat content with the firebase.

However, I got the error `_this3.navigateTo is not a function` with code below:

```
let ref = FirebaseClient.database().ref('/Chat'); 
ref.orderByChild("chatId").equalTo(chatId).once("value", function(snapshot) {

    chatId = taskId + "_" + user1Id + "_" + user2Id;
    if (snapshot.val() == null) {
        ref.push({
            chatId: chatId,
            taskId: taskId,
            user1Id: user1Id,
            user2Id: user2Id,
        })
    }
    try {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("CurrentChatId", chatId).then(res => { 
            this.navigateTo('chat');
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    }
}
```

The function `navigateTo` is copied from the demo app of NativeBase

```
import { actions } from 'react-native-navigation-redux-helpers';
import { closeDrawer } from './drawer';

const {
  replaceAt,
  popRoute,
  pushRoute,
} = actions;

export default function navigateTo(route, homeRoute) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const navigation = getState().cardNavigation;
    const currentRouteKey = navigation.routes[navigation.routes.length - 1].key;

    dispatch(closeDrawer());

    if (currentRouteKey !== homeRoute && route !== homeRoute) {
      dispatch(replaceAt(currentRouteKey, { key: route, index: 1 }, navigation.key));
    } else if (currentRouteKey !== homeRoute && route === homeRoute) {
      dispatch(popRoute(navigation.key));
    } else if (currentRouteKey === homeRoute && route !== homeRoute) {
      dispatch(pushRoute({ key: route, index: 1 }, navigation.key));
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should *bind* this to the function that contains  the *try* & *catch*. The best practice is to add this bind the *constructor* of the the component:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.myFunctoin = this.myfuction.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I have tried to bind the function but it does not help. I have shown more code now. Does it related to the `function(snapshot) { ... }` thing?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the problem. It is really because `this.navigateTo('chat');` is inside `function(snapshot)`

```
ref.orderByChild("chatId").equalTo(chatId).once("value", function(snapshot) {

    chatId = taskId + "_" + user1Id + "_" + user2Id;
    if (snapshot.val() == null) {
        ref.push({
            chatId: chatId,
            taskId: taskId,
            user1Id: user1Id,
            user2Id: user2Id,
        })
    }
}
try {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("CurrentChatId", chatId).then(res => { 
        this.navigateTo('chat');
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
}
```

Take it out from the function will solve the problem.